# Views Grouping field position

Tags: views

I have a view and i use a date field for grouping. The position of the grouping field is at the top of the view row.
Is it possible to position the grouping field at the bottom of the view row?

Answer (score 0):

With a view template file it was possible to place the grouping field at the bottom of the View.